# Share content between two different sites in same domain

Tags: options, sharing

I am trying to accomplish something weird... I have a client who wants to have two different sites to share the same content (some post types and pages).

I warned him about SEO problems, but he still wants to do it.

I have searched a lot, but haven't found a solution.

Does anybody have any idea for make this work?

Best regards.

Comment: Have you [searched](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=) [wordpress.se]?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to create another wp_options table an point the 1st domain to wp_options and the 2nd domain to wp_other_options. And use the same wp-config to both domains...
Will this work?